# Generating HTML content using Mustache.js and JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, mustache

I try to generate HTML content with Mustache.js and a JSON File

This is my JSON File which is generated with PHP

```
[
 {
    "titel": "headline",
    "tags": "tags, tags",
    "media": "statisch",
    "teaser": "css3.png"
 },
 {
    "titel": "headline2",
    "tags": "tags, tags",
    "media": "statisch",
    "teaser": "html5.png"
 }
]
```

Here is what i did in the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data, template, html;

$.getJSON('item.json', function(data) {
    var template = $('#itemGen').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('#output').html(html);    
});

</script>
<script id="itemGen" type="text/javascript">
{{#.}}
  <div class="myItem">
    <h1>{{titel}}</h1>
    <p>{{tags}}</p>
    <p>{{media}}</p>
    <img src="upload/{{teaser}}">
  </div>
{{/.}}
</script>
```

So it basically works, but it only takes the last entry of the JSON file and doesn't care about the first one. I want to get a new "myItem" DIV for each entry in my JSON File. I tried a lot of stuff from here but i can't fix it.

I hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the JSON file, it only needed the .each() function and now it works!

Here is what i did:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data, template, html;

$.getJSON('item.json', function(data) {
    var template = $('#itemGen').html();

    $.each(data, function(){
        var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
        $('#output').html(html);  
    });   
});

</script>
```

Maybe it helps someone in the future!

Comment: Your original example works, you only need to change the type of template to `text/template`, or it will be executed as javascript. I didn't know that dot notation works with [top-level arrays](https://github.com/mustache/mustache/issues/129) (it's not documented). This answer has one big flaw. All items in json will be rendered on each iteration. Use `console.log(html)` inside each and you will see. So you need to append html like: `$('#output').append(Mustache.render( $('#itemGen').html(), this));` or without the each loop: `$('#output').html( Mustache.render($('#itemGen').html(), data));`

Comment: It only rendered a single json entry without the each function, now it iterates through the json and generates for every entry the templated code. Thats all what i wanted, or do you think there will be a problem with more Json entrys? When im getting into trouble i will try your examples.. Thank you for your Help! :)

Answer (score 1):

To loop over collection of items you must have data structured like this:

```
{
  "items": [
    { "titel": "headline", ... },
    { "titel": "headline2", ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

In your case something like:

```
var html = Mustache.render( $('#itemGen').html(), { items: data } );
$('#output').html( html );
```

Also, to include the template in HTML use `<script id="itemGen" type="text/template">`, example:

```
<script id="itemGen" type="text/template">
{{#items}}
    <div class="myItem">
        <h1>{{titel}}</h1>
        <p>{{tags}}</p>
        <p>{{media}}</p>
        <img src="upload/{{teaser}}">
    </div>
{{/items}}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi There! Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work.. I think i have to rebuild the JSON File.. but there are so many different types of getting it worked with mustache.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You've probably misunderstood something, but, I would not agree that it doesn't work.

Comment: i couldn't set the curly brackets in the jQuery function.. The Tip with text/template was great! :)